# How to loop inside a dictionary which has values as arrays

Tags: python

I want to loop inside a dictionary that has arrays as values and get each element of the array. How do I do that? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
array = {'Secretary' : [0,1,2,3,4] , 'Admin' : [0,2,3,4,1]}

for key,value in array.items():
    for v in value:
        print(v[count])
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. What is `count`?

Comment: `count` has no role to play here

Comment: It seems you just want to print the values. In that case, just use `for v in value: print(v)`

Comment: count is to get the  index to print the elements

Comment: @Boutros: You don't need extra variable for index to print the elements. `for v in value: print(v)` is enough **unless** you want to do something else with the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to use `count` as an indexer. But this isn't necessary are you iterating over the *elements of each list* for each dictionary value. In addition, for iterating over values *only*, you can use the `dict.values` view. So you can use:

```
for value in array.values():
    for v in value:
        print(v)
```

If you wish to create a list combining all elements in all list values, you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

array = {'Secretary' : [0,1,2,3,4] , 'Admin' : [0,2,3,4,1]}

res = list(chain.from_iterable(array.values()))

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a complete list of all the values by pulling each item from within `d.values()`

```
d = {'Secretary' : [0,1,2,3,4] , 'Admin' : [0,2,3,4,1]}
l = [i for v in d.values() for i in v]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Expanded

```
l = []
for v in d.values():
    for i in v:
        l.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic idea right. There are a few ways you can do this. I recommend reading py docs for the classes dict, enum, and list; create solutions using all of them; and to document your code with explanations of what's happening for each of them. It sounds kind of 'douchey', and I apologize for that, but it's important to understand how to read/use this information.

As to fixing the errors in your code snippet:

```
a_dict={'Secretary' : [0,1,2,3,4] , 'Admin' : [0,2,3,4,1]} #because this is a dict OF arrays.

for key,value in a_dict.items(): #what this does. (hint, use the word tuple)  
    count = 0 #initialize the value of count to 0  
    while count < len(value):
        print(value[count])
        count =count+1
     count = 0 #reset the value of count to 0
```

Another way to do this:

```
a_dict={'Secretary' : [0,1,2,3,4] , 'Admin' : [0,2,3,4,1]} #because this is a dict OF arrays.
for values in a_dict.values(): #what this does. (hint, method from dict class)
    for value in values:        
        print(value)
```

And another:

```
a_dict={'Secretary' : [0,1,2,3,4] , 'Admin' : [0,2,3,4,1]} #because this is a dict OF arrays.
for values in a_dict.values(): #what this does. (hint, method from dict class)
    for idx in range(len(values)): #code comments are very useful        
        print(values[idx])
```

One more just for because:

```
a_dict={'Secretary' : [0,1,2,3,4] , 'Admin' : [0,2,3,4,1]} #because this is a dict OF arrays.
for key in a_dict.keys(): #what this does. (hint, method from dict class)
    vals = a_dict.get(key)          
    for idx,value in enumerate(vals): #code comments are very useful        
        print(key + ':', value, '\n')
```

If you're struggling to understand the docs, then that's what you should ask for help on. Just be specific with what you're not understanding, and keep at it. You're not always going to feel like you need a manual on how to understand the manual. This is just python however. It has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Enum? Why is that even remotely relevant?

Comment: Your indentation is all messed up

Comment: Arrays and lists are not interchangeable terms in Python

Comment: Good catch about Django

Comment: @MadPhysicist It is as relevant as assuming that all the OP wants to do is print out the values while the only thing being asked is how to iterate through every value. The fact of the matter is, we don't know what needs to happen with items in the dictionary. I also cannot (read will not) assume what research the OP has done prior to posting this question, or what specifically is misunderstood. This isn't laziness on my end. There are a lot of great explanations that are already out there. Some of them provided by users on stackoverflow.